# Не знаю почему не работает

Tags: python

Напишите программу, которая в последовательности целых чисел определяет количество чисел, кратных 5 или 9. Программа получает на вход целые числа, количество введённых чисел неизвестно, последовательность чисел заканчивается числом 0 (0 – признак окончания ввода, не входит в последовательность). Количество чисел не превышает 1000. Введённые числа по модулю не превышают 30 000. Программа должна вывести одно число: количество чисел, кратных 5 или 9.

Sample Input:

1 5 9 0
Sample Output:

2

```
s = -1
d = 0
while s == 0:
    s = int(input())
    if s % 5 == 0 or s % 9 == 0:
        d = d + 1
print(d)
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы не правильно понимаете как работает цикл `while`. Ваш цикл выполняет только когда S равен 0! А вам нужно чтобы при вводе 0 - цикл (и подсчет) завершался!

```
s = -1
d = 0
while True:
    s = int(input())
    if s == 0:
        break
    if s % 5 == 0 or s % 9 == 0:
        d = d + 1
print(d)
```

`break` завершит бесконечный цикл по условию.

Но даже этот код не решение вашей задачи, т.к. не учтено `Количество чисел не превышает 1000` и `Введённые числа по модулю не превышают 30 000`

Comment: *т.к. не учтено* Забыл проверки на то, что введено число, а если да - то что оно целое. ;)

Comment: @Akina это учебные задания, лучше делать всё как в `ТЗ` =)

Comment: Не, просто получается, что ты одни утверждения ТЗ подвергаешь сомнению и требуешь как-то учитывать их (интересно, как? начать игнорить те вводы, которые не соответствуют?), а другие почему-то нет..

Comment: `т.к. не учтено` -  Не нужно это проверять, это как бы справочная информация для решающего (например, если бы было 10^12, то в типизированных языках нужно было бы 64-битный тип использовать), и соблюдение обеспечивается  проверяющей системой.